# Desktop Background completely messed up

Tags: system, nvidia

I decided to switch my desktop computer to Ubuntu, but every desktop I have tried has had completely messed up backgrounds. On Budgie, I could temporarily fix it by changing the background, but not on Elementary OS. I have had issues similar to this on another computer, and removing the graphics card fixed it. Unfortunately, that is not an option here. I am using a Nvidia GeForce 7300 LE, if that helps.
Here are [some various examples.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1gsL.jpg)

Comment: Press print screen or find in Google how to install any screenshot software in Elementary and how to use print screen button on your keyboard. Bear in mind that some software may use ctrl+print screen buttons. You actually did not write anything which would let me to understand your problem. What background? On a screen lock or on desktop?

Comment: On desktop. I know how to take a screenshot, but not how to upload it.

Comment: I ended up lust uploading some screenshots to imgur

Comment: Then provide links to imgur.

Comment: Have you tried switch nvidia driver? You can do that in appcenter.

Comment: Unfortunately, Nvidia dropped support for my graphics card. On Windows, I was able to install an older driver, but I have been unsuccessful with doing that on Ubuntu. I was able to download an installer, but it's unable to build the Nvidia kernel module. According to the log, nvidia.ko failed to build right before the installation failed.